# Como atualizar todos os registros de todas as tabelas que tenham FK de uma tabela

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server, entity-framework, ddd

Tenho as seguintes tabelas:

```
CREATE TABLE Contrato (
  [Id [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
  [Nome] [varchar](150),
  [Ativo] [bit]
  PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ItemContrato] (
  [Id] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
  [ContratoId] [int],
  [Nome] [varchar](150),
  [Ativo] [bit]
  PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
)
 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ItemContrato] ADD FOREIGN KEY ([ContratoId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Contrato] ([Id]);
```

Com os seguintes registros:

```
 Contrato
 Id | Nome      | Ativo
 1  |Contrato A |  1
 2  |Contrato B |  1

 ItemContrato
 Id | ContratoId | Nome                | Ativo
 1  |     1      |Item de Contrato A1  |  1
 2  |     1      |Item de Contrato A2  |  1
 3  |     2      |Item de Contrato B1  |  1
```

Quero saber se há como, ou qual a melhor maneira para: Quando eu der um UPDATE na tabela Contrato setando Ativo = 0, o mesmo seja feito em todas as tabelas que tenham uma chave estrangeira da tabela Contrato.

Estou criando uma aplicação usando ASP.NET MVC com EntityFramework e DDD.

Obrigado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A melhor solução seria não replicar a informação para a tabela `ItemContrato`, afinal isso seria redundância. A melhor forma seria buscar a informação direto da tabela de origem:

```
SELECT ic.id,
       ic.contratoid,
       ic.nome,
       c.ativo
  FROM ItemContrato ic WITH(NOLOCK)
       INNER JOIN Contrato c WITH(NOLOCK) ON c.id = ic.contratoid;
```

---

Porém caso realmente queira replicar a informação, sugiro a utilização de uma `trigger` para realizar a alteração:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tgr_contrato_aiu', 'TR') IS NULL
BEGIN
  EXEC('CREATE TRIGGER tgr_contrato_aiu ON Contrato FOR INSERT, UPDATE AS BEGIN SELECT 1 END');
END;
GO

ALTER TRIGGER tgr_contrato_aiu
ON Contrato
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @nome_tabela VARCHAR(100),
          @query       VARCHAR(MAX);

  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  -- Pega o nome da tabela para a qual a TRIGGER é executada
  SELECT @nome_tabela = OBJECT_NAME(o.parent_object_id)
    FROM sys.objects o WITH(NOLOCK)
   WHERE o.name = OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID);

  SELECT @query = isnull(@query + CHAR(10), '') + 'UPDATE f' + CHAR(10) +
                                                  '   SET f.ativo = ' +  + CAST(i.ativo AS VARCHAR) + CHAR(10) +
                                                  '  FROM ' + tf.name + ' f' + CHAR(10) +
                                                  ' WHERE f.' + c.name + ' = ' + CAST(i.id AS VARCHAR) + ';' + CHAR(10)
    FROM sys.tables t WITH(NOLOCK)
         INNER JOIN sys.foreign_keys fk WITH(NOLOCK) ON fk.referenced_object_id = t.object_id
         INNER JOIN sys.tables tf WITH(NOLOCK) ON tf.object_id = fk.parent_object_id
         INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns fkc WITH(NOLOCK) ON fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
         INNER JOIN sys.columns c WITH(NOLOCK) ON c.object_id = fkc.parent_object_id
                                              AND c.column_id = fkc.parent_column_id
         CROSS JOIN inserted i
         INNER JOIN deleted d ON d.id = i.id
   WHERE t.name = @nome_tabela
     -- Somente se mudar algo na coluna "Ativo"
     AND i.ativo <> d.ativo
     -- Garante que exista a coluna "Ativo" na tabela filha
     AND EXISTS(SELECT 1
                  FROM sys.columns cf WITH(NOLOCK)
                 WHERE cf.object_id = fkc.parent_object_id
                   AND cf.name = 'ATIVO');

  IF @query IS NOT NULL
  BEGIN
    -- PRINT @query;
    EXEC(@query);
  END;
END;
GO
```

A `trigger` acima busca todas as chaves estrangeiras relacionadas a tabela `Contrato`, juntamente com suas colunas e, dinamicamente, atualiza a coluna `Ativo` de acordo com o valor que foi inserido. Note que a `trigger` é executadas **depois** de cada `INSERT` e `UPDATE`.

Sugiro também a criação de uma `trigger` para a tabela `ItemContrato` que garantirá que quando um novo registro for inserido, já esteja com a informação da coluna `Ativo` da maneira que é esperada:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tgr_itemcontrato_ai', 'TR') IS NULL
BEGIN
  EXEC('CREATE TRIGGER tgr_itemcontrato_ai ON ItemContrato FOR INSERT AS BEGIN SELECT 1 END');
END;
GO

ALTER TRIGGER tgr_itemcontrato_ai
ON ItemContrato
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  UPDATE ic
     SET ic.ativo = c.ativo
    FROM ItemContrato ic
         INNER JOIN inserted i ON i.id = ic.id
         INNER JOIN Contrato c ON c.id = ic.contratoid;
END;
GO
```

---

Para teste utilizei as seguintes inclusões nas tabelas:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @ultimo_codigo INT;

-- Inserção dos dados para teste
-- Contrato "X"
INSERT INTO Contrato(nome, ativo)
              VALUES('X', 1);
SET @ultimo_codigo = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

INSERT INTO ItemContrato(contratoid, nome)
                  VALUES(@ultimo_codigo, 'A'),
                        (@ultimo_codigo, 'B'),
                        (@ultimo_codigo, 'C');

-- Contrato "Y"
INSERT INTO Contrato(nome, ativo)
              VALUES('Y', 1);
SET @ultimo_codigo = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

INSERT INTO ItemContrato(contratoid, nome)
                  VALUES(@ultimo_codigo, 'D'),
                        (@ultimo_codigo, 'E'),
                        (@ultimo_codigo, 'F'),
                        (@ultimo_codigo, 'G');

-- Contrato "Z"
INSERT INTO Contrato(nome, ativo)
              VALUES('Z', 0);
SET @ultimo_codigo = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

INSERT INTO ItemContrato(contratoid, nome)
                  VALUES(@ultimo_codigo, 'H'),
                        (@ultimo_codigo, 'I'),
                        (@ultimo_codigo, 'J');
```

Obtendo os resultados a seguir logo após a inserção:

```
╔════╦══════╦═══════╗
║ Id ║ Nome ║ Ativo ║
╠════╬══════╬═══════╣
║ 1  ║ X    ║ 1     ║
║ 2  ║ Y    ║ 1     ║
║ 3  ║ Z    ║ 0     ║
╚════╩══════╩═══════╝

╔════╦════════════╦══════╦═══════╗
║ Id ║ ContratoId ║ Nome ║ Ativo ║
╠════╬════════════╬══════╬═══════╣
║ 1  ║ 1          ║ A    ║ 1     ║
║ 2  ║ 1          ║ B    ║ 1     ║
║ 3  ║ 1          ║ C    ║ 1     ║
║ 4  ║ 2          ║ D    ║ 1     ║
║ 5  ║ 2          ║ E    ║ 1     ║
║ 6  ║ 2          ║ F    ║ 1     ║
║ 7  ║ 2          ║ G    ║ 1     ║
║ 8  ║ 3          ║ H    ║ 0     ║
║ 9  ║ 3          ║ I    ║ 0     ║
║10  ║ 3          ║ J    ║ 0     ║
╚════╩════════════╩══════╩═══════╝
```

Logo após realizei o seguinte `UPDATE`:

```
-- Atualização dos contratos "X" e "Z"
UPDATE c
   SET c.ativo = 0
  FROM Contrato c
 WHERE c.nome = 'X';

UPDATE c
   SET c.ativo = 1
  FROM Contrato c
 WHERE c.nome = 'Z';
```

E os registros após o `UPDATE` são:

```
╔════╦══════╦═══════╗
║ Id ║ Nome ║ Ativo ║
╠════╬══════╬═══════╣
║ 1  ║ X    ║ 0     ║
║ 2  ║ Y    ║ 1     ║
║ 3  ║ Z    ║ 1     ║
╚════╩══════╩═══════╝

╔════╦════════════╦══════╦═══════╗
║ Id ║ ContratoId ║ Nome ║ Ativo ║
╠════╬════════════╬══════╬═══════╣
║ 1  ║ 1          ║ A    ║ 0     ║
║ 2  ║ 1          ║ B    ║ 0     ║
║ 3  ║ 1          ║ C    ║ 0     ║
║ 4  ║ 2          ║ D    ║ 1     ║
║ 5  ║ 2          ║ E    ║ 1     ║
║ 6  ║ 2          ║ F    ║ 1     ║
║ 7  ║ 2          ║ G    ║ 1     ║
║ 8  ║ 3          ║ H    ║ 1     ║
║ 9  ║ 3          ║ I    ║ 1     ║
║10  ║ 3          ║ J    ║ 1     ║
╚════╩════════════╩══════╩═══════╝
```

No caso da primeira `query` proposta os resultados antes do `UPDATE` para a tabela `ItemContrato` foram:

```
╔════╦════════════╦══════╦═══════╗
║ Id ║ ContratoId ║ Nome ║ Ativo ║
╠════╬════════════╬══════╬═══════╣
║ 1  ║ 1          ║ A    ║ 1     ║
║ 2  ║ 1          ║ B    ║ 1     ║
║ 3  ║ 1          ║ C    ║ 1     ║
║ 4  ║ 2          ║ D    ║ 1     ║
║ 5  ║ 2          ║ E    ║ 1     ║
║ 6  ║ 2          ║ F    ║ 1     ║
║ 7  ║ 2          ║ G    ║ 1     ║
║ 8  ║ 3          ║ H    ║ 0     ║
║ 9  ║ 3          ║ I    ║ 0     ║
║10  ║ 3          ║ J    ║ 0     ║
╚════╩════════════╩══════╩═══════╝
```

E após o `UPDATE`:

```
╔════╦════════════╦══════╦═══════╗
║ Id ║ ContratoId ║ Nome ║ Ativo ║
╠════╬════════════╬══════╬═══════╣
║ 1  ║ 1          ║ A    ║ 0     ║
║ 2  ║ 1          ║ B    ║ 0     ║
║ 3  ║ 1          ║ C    ║ 0     ║
║ 4  ║ 2          ║ D    ║ 1     ║
║ 5  ║ 2          ║ E    ║ 1     ║
║ 6  ║ 2          ║ F    ║ 1     ║
║ 7  ║ 2          ║ G    ║ 1     ║
║ 8  ║ 3          ║ H    ║ 1     ║
║ 9  ║ 3          ║ I    ║ 1     ║
║10  ║ 3          ║ J    ║ 1     ║
╚════╩════════════╩══════╩═══════╝
```

Note que os resultados são os mesmos, provando assim que para este caso a utilização do `JOIN` para evitar a redundância é a melhor opção.

Answer (score 3):

Levando em conta que você tenha um contexto `Context`.

```
var result = Context.Contrato.Include(rel => rel.ItemContrato).FirstOrDefault(prop => prop.Id == id);
```

Nesse código eu carrego minha entidade Contrato a ser modificada e todos ItemContrato relacionado a ela, você pode alterar a expressão do `FirstOrDefault` de acordo com o seu gosto.

```
Context.Entry(result).State = EntityState.Modified;
result.Ativo = 0;
foreach (var itemContrato in result.ItemContratos)
{
    itemContrato.Ativo = 0;
    Context.Entry(itemContrato).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
Context.SaveChanges();
```

Pode não ser a melhor maneira a ser feito, mas vai resolver seu problema.

Comment: Não entendi exatamente onde deveria fazer essa implementação, tenho pouca experiência com essa estrutura que estou trabalhando. Mas sim, tenho um Context

Comment: No DDD isso vai dentro de sua camada de persistência, pode ser um repository pattern que você esteja utilizando, ou outro padrão.

Comment: No meu caso eu tenho um repositório com os métodos especializados da entidade Contrato. Devo fazer um override do meu método Update?

Comment: Não, porque essa implementação é um **cenário especifico** onde o seu update vai adicionar um Ativo igual a zero, se quiser sobrescrever o seu base.Update(), você precisa alterar meu exemplo.

Comment: Na verdade é um cenário que deve ocorrer em todas as situações. Minha intenção é, ao torar um registro inativo, todos "filhos" desse registro também se tornem inativos. Me disseram que poderia fazer com trigger também, mas ainda não sei qual seria a melhor opção

Comment: Trigger também poderia ser utilizado para um resultado parecido.